# How to avoid not to query tables or views in scalar functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have scalar functions( 4 functions) in my View. It drastically reduces the view's performance. I believe the reason for that is I use SELECT queries in my scalar functions.

EG:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_BJs_GENERAL]
    (
      @TankSystemId int,
      @TimeStamp datetime2(7)
    )
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @leakChk varchar(10);
    DECLARE @allowableVariance float;
    DECLARE @GallonsPumped int;
    DECLARE @DailyOverOrShort float;
    DECLARE @TimePeriod datetime2(7);
    DECLARE @ReportDate datetime2(7)
    SELECT TOP 1 @TimePeriod = Date 
    FROM [bjs].udv_DailySiraData
    where TankSystemId=@TankSystemId  ORDER BY Date DESC

        SET @ReportDate=@TimePeriod
        IF( @TimeStamp <= @TimePeriod)
          SET @ReportDate=@TimeStamp 

        SELECT @GallonsPumped  = SUM(GallonsPumped)
            FROM [bjs].[udv_DailySiraData] 
            where TankSystemId=@TankSystemId  
              and Date <=@ReportDate and Date >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@ReportDate), 0)
        SELECT @DailyOverOrShort = SUM(DailyVar)  
            FROM [bjs].[udv_DailySiraData] 
            where TankSystemId=@TankSystemId
              and Date <=@ReportDate and Date >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@ReportDate), 0)

        SELECT @allowableVariance= (@GallonsPumped/100) + 130

        SET @leakChk='FAIL'
        IF (@allowableVariance > ABS(@DailyOverOrShort))
             SET @leakChk = 'PASS'

RETURN @leakChk;
```

How can i avoid such situations? Is there a way to do select queries in my View and pass that result to my scalar function?

Comment: Yes, If you have query in a scalar function, will make your query very slow, in this situation, I re-write a view instead of the function and join into the query

Comment: @NolanShang any sample code would be really helpful?

Comment: The problem is using any scalar function in a view, try to avoid scalar functions. The likelihood is that individually they may be fine/reasonable but in a view you are most probably firing off these functions on every result row so 100 row @4 scalar functions = 400 calls * the number of selects in each function = (say) 800 selects, per 100 rows. And it gets worse for performance if you are using those functions in any where clause.

Comment: @Used_By_Already What is your best advice for such scenarios? How can I replace scalar functions in Views?

Comment: You have to figure that out I'm afraid as you need to meet the functional requirements which I know nothing of. You might find that flipping the solution on its head works better because the best performing functions are those that return tables. So maybe you need these instead of views? The point is you are mot likely approaching the requirements like a "structured program" and SQL isn't  really suited to that. View are views, don't try to make them parameterized, just use a where clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create function dbo.udf_BJs_GENERAL(
    @TankSystemId int,
    @TimeStamp    datetime2(7)
) returns varchar(10) as 
with dates as (
    select top 1
        ReportDate = case when @TimeStamp <= Date then @TimeStamp else Date
    from bjs.udv_DailySiraData
    where TankSystemId=@TankSystemId
    order by Date desc
),
gallons as (
    select
        allowableVariance = ( sum(GallonsPumped)/100) + 130,
        DailyOverOrShort  = sum(DailyVar) 
    from bjs.udv_DailySiraData data
    join dates
       on data.Date <= dates.ReportDate
      and date.Date >= dateadd(mm, datediffmm, 0, dates.ReportDate), 0)

    where TankSystemId = @TankSystemId
)
select 
    leakChk = cast( case when allowableVariance > ABS(DailyOverOrShort))
                    then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end as varchar(10) )
from gallons
```

Comment: May I know, what is the difference here? I mean the sample function I put in the question has more readable. Sorry, I couldn't understand above function rewritten manner?

Comment: @Ratha: It is an *inline, table-valued* function rather than a *multi-line, scalar* function. Thus it is optimized the same as any view would be (though parameterized), and thus does not suffer the performance degradation of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

your case is special, your have a special input parameter,assue the timestamp parameter is on Day level
This view will return check result of each TankSystemId on every day.
Then join will your query with TankSystemId and Day.
But if the input parameter is more detail. I think it is difficult to convert this function to view

```
    CREATE view [dbo].[uvw_BJs_GENERAL]
    AS 
    BEGIN

    /*
            SET @ReportDate=@TimePeriod
            IF( @TimeStamp <= @TimePeriod)
              SET @ReportDate=@TimeStamp 
    */
            SELECT TankSystemId,b.[Date]
                   ,GallonsPumped  = SUM(GallonsPumped),DailyOverOrShort = SUM(DailyVar) 
                   ,leakChk=CASE WHEN  (SUM(GallonsPumped)/100) + 130)> ABS(SUM(DailyVar)) THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END 
                FROM [bjs].[udv_DailySiraData] AS a
                INNER JOIN (
                   SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) AS [Date] FROM  [bjs].[udv_DailySiraData] GROUP BY  TankSystemId, CONVERT(DATE,[Date])
                ) b ON a.TankSystemId=b.TankSystemId AND  DATEDIFF(d,a.[Date],b.[Date])>=0
               --   and Date <=@ReportDate and Date >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@ReportDate), 0)

                 GROUP BY TankSystemId,b.[Date]

    END
```